# Custom UITableViewCell background color

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to change tablecell's background color.
Here is code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstMainViewTableCells") as! FirstMainViewTableCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 43, green: 65, blue: 87, alpha: 1)

    return cell
}
```

And here is result:

[Screenshot](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/IMG_0085.jpg?_subject_uid=342603655&w=AADndn_Ls2OtLXEFi2yka-hyLUdlH1udZowaDOh2yY50uw)

But it works with UIColor.blackColor() and UIColor.  colors:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstMainViewTableCells") as! FirstMainViewTableCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return cell
}
```

[Second Screenshot](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/IMG_0084.jpg?_subject_uid=342603655&w=AADXr6czIU6WinKlYkiBgeS7wsaU887KOrCZUrE6F2crcw)

Can you help me?

Comment: i got 403 error page, cant view your dropbox.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin We dont even need the link, its obvious that the background will be black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Color** in iOS ranges between `0-1`. You need to add **255** as factor to get correct color code, see below

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 65/255.0, blue: 87/255.0, alpha: 1);
```

It should work.

Cheers.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, i forgot about it. It works fine now.